# Start Neo4j from a shell script on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: bash, shell

From the command line, I can start Neo4j with a command like:

```
~/neo4j/bin/neo4j start
```

How can I do this from inside a shell script?

start.sh

```
# Define defaults
path_default="~/neo4j/bin/neo4j"
port_default="7474"
pass_default="1234"

# Ask for custom values
read -p "Enter path to neo4j [$path_default]: " path
path="${path:-$path_default}"
read -p "Enter port to neo4j [$port_default]: " port
port="${port:-$port_default}"
read -p "Enter password for neo4j [$pass_default]: " pass
pass="${pass:-$pass_default}"

if !(lsof -t -i:$port); then
  echo "Starting Neo4j"
  "$path start" #THIS IS NOT WORKING
fi
```

I get the following error when I run `./start.sh`:

```
./start.sh: line 16: ~/neo4j/bin/neo4j start: No such file or directory
```

---

EDIT: On Mac OS X, if I use `/Users/$USER/neo4j/bin/neo4j` instead of `~/neo4j/bin/neo4j`, everything works fine. So one way to solve my problem would be to convert `~` to `/Users/$USER`, if the user entered a path beginning with `~` on a Mac. But would this work on all platforms?

---

EDIT: Following the suggestions of @DannyDaglas, I have altered my start.sh script to:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define defaults
path_default="~/neo4j/bin/neo4j"
port_default="7474"

# Ask for custom values
read -p "Enter path to neo4j [$path_default]: " path
path="${path:-$path_default}"
read -p "Enter port to neo4j [$port_default]: " port
port="${port:-$port_default}"

if !(lsof -t -i:$port); then
  echo "Starting Neo4j at $path"
  $(cd / ; ls $path) start
fi
```

This is still failing. Here is the output in the Terminal when I accept the default values:

```
$ ./start.sh
Enter path to neo4j [~/neo4j/bin/neo4j]: 
Enter port to neo4j [7474]: 
Starting Neo4j at ~/neo4j/bin/neo4j
ls: ~/neo4j/bin/neo4j: No such file or directory
./start.sh: line 38: start: command not found
```

Note: This is on a new install of Mac OS 10.10.5 Yosemite.

Answer (score -1):

Eliminate the double quotes:

```
  $path start
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I get: `Starting Neo4j` and then `./start.sh: line 16: ~/neo4j/bin/neo4j: No such file or directory`

Comment: Specify the shell on top of the file with #!/bin/bash   I suspect that you are using a shell that you are not expecting.

Comment: Using `#!/bin/bash` doesn't help. It looks as if, on Mac OS 10.10 at least, the `~` symbol is not being resolved to `/Users/$USER`.

Comment: Can you check that the $HOME variable is set?  ~ resolves to $HOME if I recall correctly.

Comment: And if that yields no solution, brute-force it with: $(cd / ; ls $path) start

Comment: Still no joy. `echo $HOME` and `echo ~` both respond with `/Users/james`. I've made all the changes that you have suggested, as an edit to my question, and given the output.